# How to display a statement at a specfic row and column using Term::Cap module in perl

Tags: perl, terminal, termcap

I writing a code which will display a statement at 2 nd row and 10th column using Term::Cap module in perl .

I have tried the below code

```
#!/apps/perl/5.8.9/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;

require POSIX;
use Term::Cap;

my $termios =new  POSIX::Termios;
$termios->getattr;
my $ospeed =$termios->getospeed;

my $terminal = Tgetent Term::Cap {TERM=>undef, OSPEED=>$ospeed};
$terminal->Trequire(qw/ce ku kd/);
$terminal->Tgoto('cm',5,2);
print "Hello World\n";
$terminal->Tputs('c1');
```

I am getting output without any row and column position which I specific. Also what will  Trequire(), Tgetent(), do . Also is it possible to display Hello in (r1,c1) and World at (r1,c2).

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was partly incorrect, I've corrected it.

The [Term::Cap](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Cap) module is for manipulating a simple, antiquated terminal-related database. From the description:

> These are low-level functions to extract and use capabilities from a
>   terminal capability (termcap) database.

This database may not be present on a modern implementation of Unix (e.g. Linux). The perl module uses `infocmp -C` to obtain the terminal information if it cannot find the database file.

I think your example is based on the documentation which appears a little misleading with its use of `$FH`. The `print` statement in perl is simply going to standard output and will be devoid of any positioning because `Tgoto` returns the control characters for the positioning. It can be used for positioning in two ways:

```
print $terminal->Tgoto('cm',5,2);
```

or

```
$terminal->Tgoto('cm',5,2,*STDOUT);
```

You are likely to also want to automatically flush standard output too to avoid buffering effects, see below for a complete example which also features correct use of `Trequire`:

```
use Term::Cap;
use strict;

my $ospeed = 9600; 
my $terminal = Tgetent Term::Cap { TERM => undef, OSPEED => $ospeed };
$terminal->Trequire(qw/cl cm/);

STDOUT->autoflush(1);          ### turn off buffering
print $terminal->Tputs('cl');  ### clear screen

my ($row, $col) = (16, 10);

foreach my $word (reverse(qw(ALL YOUR TERMCAP ARE BELONG TO US))) {
  sleep(1);
  print $terminal->Tgoto('cm', $row, $col--);  ### position cursor
  print $word;
}

print $terminal->Tgoto('cm', 0, 18);
```

`Trequire` is checking the **term**inal you are using the **cap**abilities you are using in the program represented by the short [termcap character codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html#SEC44). In the progam above: `cl` for clear screen and home cursor and `cm` for position cursor. It will throw an exception and terminate the program if the terminal does not support the specified list.

The ancient *higher-level* libraries in this space for unix were called curses and were used for "full-screen" commands like `vi`. A modern version of this is [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). I'd suggest looking searching for curses on [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/) to find something that has the features suitable for your use case.